# Test Promise<string> value in Angular 2 unit tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-promise

Bellow is example,and test failed- str is undefined.
        How get value from promise in angular2 ?

```
 describe('Test', () => {
        it('case of string', () => {
            let t: Promise<string> = deserializeSimpleField(...);
            let str:string;
            t.then(value=>str = value);
            expect(str).toEqual('name');
        });});
```

Answer (score 4):

Async execution is contagious. You can't go back to sync execution.

```
describe('Test', () => {
    it('case of string', inject([AsyncTestCompleter], (async: AsyncTestCompleter) => {
        deserializeSimpleField(...)
        .then(value => {
          expect(value).toEqual('name');
          async.done();
        });
    });
});
```

I looked it up in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/forms/test/form_array_spec.ts

**update**

```
describe('Test', () => {
    it('case of string', async(() => {
        return deserializeSimpleField(...)
        .then(value => {
          expect(value).toEqual('name');
          async.done();
        });
    }));
});
```

Comment: Dear @Gunter I use @angular/testing ,and there AsyncTestCompleter  is missing?. Is exists way do it by @angular/testing?

Comment: actually I don't know what the correct and current way is to do async testing. I wasn't able to find anything in the changelog neither. I just looked up a test in the github repo that was recently updated. Can you please try my updated answer? (not sure if the added `return` is required).

Comment: updated version brings :
 TypeError: AsyncTestZoneSpec is not a constructor
        at runInAsyncTestZone

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: Thank you very match,for ideas dear @Gunter

Comment: The updated approach is also used in https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/2198/files Perhaps these docs can help you to figure out how to fix your issue.

Comment: You don't need the done() method as this is run in a zone in Angular 2 - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126729/angular-2-testing-async-function-call-when-to-use#40127164

Answer (score 3):

```
I resolve question following way,(using  fakeAsync,tick..)

require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
import {describe, it, expect, fakeAsync, tick} from '@angular/testing'
describe('my first test', () => {
    it('Promises fulfilled by tick',fakeAsync((): void => {
        let promise:Promise<number> =Promise.resolve(11);
        let x:number;
        promise.then( v => {
            x = v;
        });
        tick();
        expect(x).toBe(11);
    }));
});
```

Comment: Dear @Gunter please see the solution.

Comment: The only difference seems to be `fake`, right? (and `tick();`)

Comment: Yeah.  
tick()- Simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the fakeAsync zone.

Comment: Weird. If `fakeAsync` works, `async` should work as well. Glad to hear you found a way to make it work for you.

Comment: I think with tick() your  async(..) works as well.Thank you dear Gunter. 
p.s. I vote for  your  answer.  :)

Comment: AFAIK `tick()` is only required for `fakeAsync()`