# Angular 2 RC6 test HTTP.get throws error the get() method doesn't exist

Tags: http, angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test for a method that includes an http.get method and I'm having issues getting it to work. I know that setting the class to use for Http as MockBackend is wrong and is why I get the error: `get() method does not exist` however I don't know what I should use for the mock class behind http.

```
describe('Http Service', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        SharedHttpService,
        {
          provide: SharedCookieService,
          useClass: MockSharedCookieService
        }, {
          provide: Http,
          useClass: MockBackend
        }
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([ SharedHttpService, Http ], ( _httpService: SharedHttpService, _mockBackend: MockBackend ) => {
    httpService = _httpService;
    mockBackend = _mockBackend;
  }));

  describe('get', () => {
    it(`should call setAuthToken and make the get request with the authorization headers`, () => {
      let fakeUrl: string = 'www.fakeurl.com';
      httpService.headers = mockHeaders;
      spyOn(httpService, 'setAuthToken');
      spyOn(httpService.http, 'get').and.callThrough();
      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        let options: ResponseOptions = new ResponseOptions({
          body: { }
        });
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));
      });
      httpService.get(fakeUrl, () => { })
      .subscribe(() => {
        expect(httpService.setAuthToken).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(httpService.http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeUrl, { headers: mockHeaders });
      });
    });
  });
```

Code behind:

```
export class SharedHttpService {
  private headers: Headers = new Headers();

  constructor(  private cookieService: SharedCookieService,
                private http: Http  ) { }

  public get(address: string, callback: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.setAuthToken()
      .map(() => { })
      .switchMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(address, { headers: this.headers })
          .map(callback)
          .catch(( error: any ) => this.handleError(error));
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `MockBackend` not *as* the `Http`, but to *create* the `Http`. You do that with a factory

```
imports: [ HttpModule // this is needed ],
providers: [
  SharedHttpService,
  MockBackend,
  BaseRequestOptions    // @angular/http
  {
    provide: Http,
    deps: [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ],
    useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => {
      return new Http(backend, options);
    }
  }
]
```

Now you can inject the `MockBackend` into the tests so that you can mock the response on the connection.

```
                                  // MockBackend not Http
beforeEach(inject([ SharedHttpService, MockBackend ],
          ( _httpService: SharedHttpService, _mockBackend: MockBackend ) => {
  httpService = _httpService;
  mockBackend = _mockBackend;
}));
```

Another thing, you need to use an asynchronous test, as the call to `subscribe` resolves asynchronously

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';

it('...', async(() => {

}));
```

See also [Angular 2 Testing - Async function call - when to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40126729/2587435)