# Angular with Jasmine: is there a conflict between async in beforeEach() and async in it()?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, jasmine

My goal is to test API calls, taking delays into account. I was inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126729/angular-2-testing-async-function-call-when-to-use).

I've designed a sandbox in which a mock API takes 1000 msec to respond and change the value of a global variable `result`. The test checks the value after 500msec and after 1500msec.

Here is the code where the last test is supposed to fail:

```
    let result: number;
    
    const mockAPICall = (delay: number): Observable<number> => {
        console.log('API called');
        return Observable.of(5).delay(delay);
    };
    
    beforeEach(() => {
        console.log('before each');
    });
    
    it('time test', async(() => {
        result = 0;
        const delay = 1000;
        console.log('start');

        mockAPICall(delay).subscribe((apiResult: number) => {
            console.log('obs done');
            result = apiResult;
        });

        console.log('first check');
        expect(result).toEqual(0);

        setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('second check');
                expect(result).toEqual(0);
            }, 500
        );

        setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('third check');
                expect(result).toEqual(0);
            }, 1500
        );
    }));
```

The last test does fail as expected and I get this in the logs:

```
before each
API called
first check
second check
obs done
third check
```

Now if I place an `async()` in the `beforeEach()`:

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        console.log('async before each');
    }));
```

, the test passes and I only get this in the logs:

```
async before each
API called
first check
```

I didn't expect that. Why this behavior ? What happens behind the scenes ?

Note: I'll need this `async()` in `beforeEach()` in future tests because I'll use a `testBed` and `compileComponents`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from an unfortunate edge case using Zones during testing, and is outlined in the Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#jasmine-done).

> Writing test functions with `done()`, is more cumbersome than `async` and `fakeAsync`. But it is occasionally necessary. For example, you can't call `async` or `fakeAsync` when testing code that involves the `intervalTimer()` or the RxJS `delay()` operator.

This has to do with the implementation of timers in `rxjs`, and there's lots of good materials out there that can help you use TestSchedulers to test `rxjs` code that uses some of these operators (like `delay`).

For your case, you can choose to refactor your test to not use the `delay` operator, or you can fall back on `done()`, provided by Jasmine.

```
let result: number;

const mockAPICall = (delay: number): Observable<number> => {
    console.log('API called');
    return Observable.of(0).delay(delay); // changed from 5 -> 0, to make tests pass
};

beforeEach(async(() => {
    console.log('async before each');
}));

it('time test', done => async(() => {
    result = 0;
    const delay = 1000;
    console.log('start');

    mockAPICall(delay).subscribe((apiResult: number) => {
        console.log('obs done');
        result = apiResult;
    });

    console.log('first check');
    expect(result).toEqual(0);

    setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('second check');
            expect(result).toEqual(0);
        }, 500
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('third check');
            expect(result).toEqual(0);
            done(); // indicate that the test is complete
        }, 1500
    );
})());
```

Because there is a problem using `delay` with `async`, Jasmine is "ending" the test early - you don't see failures, but you also won't see some of the logging statements.