# Async beforeEach finished before/after each test unit(it)

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test, testbed

I am using Angular 6 and I have one concern regarding every test which I have seen so far.

Here's a simple test of simple component which is generated by cli.

```js
describe('CompComponent', () => {
  let component: CompComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CompComponent>;
    
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CompComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
    
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CompComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
    
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How do I know for certain that each Async `beforeEach` call is done before each test unit?

Are there any cases where this call will happen after each because test is an async call after all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Each `beforeEach` will finish before any test begins.**

In your example, `compileComponents()` is asynchronous. So, we must use async() method in this case.

for your reference, look to this link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4774

to be sure that your `beforeEach` will finish before any test begins, you can try to debug your test by adding this:

```
compileComponents().then( result => {
  console.log(result);
}
```

You can set a break point at this line: `console.log(result);` and you will see that it will be executed all time you run your test, so if you set a breakpoint in this `console.log' line and another one in your firt` it`test, you will see you will never get to the second break point before doing the`console.log` break point one, that means that we will have to wait for any async call inside the beforeEach before going to any test.

**Another way to see that the `beforeEach` will all time finish before any test begins is to write your test this way as well:**

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ CompComponent ]
}).compileComponents().then( result => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CompComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }
}));
```

You will see that in any of your test the `fixture` is already available, doing that way. So you don't need to add another beforeEach to initialize your `fixture`.

To understand more, you can refere to this other answer from Stack Overflow:

**[angular-2-testing-async-function-call-when-to-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126729/angular-2-testing-async-function-call-when-to-use)**