# Angular-Testing: Angular5 spyOn not working in child components

Tags: angular, angular5, karma-jasmine, angular-routing, angular-test

I have an angular app and its one child module is loading by lazy loading. I am using this code in app.routing.ts to load that module.

```
{
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            loadChildren: './views/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
        }
    ],
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
},
```

Now in all the components in dashboard module my unit testing is not working. i.e. because spyOn is not working. let me show the spec file code and actual function

```
it('be able to call getDemographicsData function from ngOnInit', () => {
        spy = spyOn(programDemographicsComponent, 'getDemographicsData').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(programDemographicsComponent, 'dateRangeHandler');
        programDemographicsComponent.ngOnInit();
        expect(programDemographicsComponent.getDemographicsData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Function that I am unit testing is:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.qualifyingProductsTableCurrentPage = 0;
        this.qualifyingProductsTableValuesPerPage = 5;
        const startDateMillis = moment().subtract(90, 'days').valueOf();
        const endDateMillis = moment().valueOf();
        this.getDemographicsData(startDateMillis, endDateMillis)
    }

    getDemographicsData(startDateMillis, endDateMillis) {
        console.log('spy is not working')
        const metricsRequestData = new MetricsRequest();
        metricsRequestData.startDateMillis = startDateMillis;
        metricsRequestData.endDateMillis = endDateMillis;
        this.getGenderData(metricsRequestData);
        this.getAgeData(metricsRequestData);
    }
```

Since I am spying the `getDemographicsData(startDateMillis, endDateMillis)` method in test cases but my `console.log('spy is not working')` is still working. 
Please let me know if any more details are needed.

PS. I have checked same issue in parent components and my spyOn is working fine in them. I am facing problem only in components with lazyloading

Comment: did you try to add fixture.detectChanges(); after  programDemographicsComponent.ngOnInit();

Comment: Please update question with what fail response you get when running test

Answer (score 0):

As lazy loading is async operation, the tests should also be async. You can see in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126729/angular-2-testing-async-function-call-when-to-use) how to make it async.